# Riemann $\zeta$-function and a series involving Stirling numbers of first kind.

Tags: sequences-and-series, alternative-proof, riemann-zeta, stirling-numbers

While answering a recent [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2733728/293846) I have realized that the series
$$S(n,m):=\sum_{k=n}^\infty{k \brack n}\frac{1}{k!(k-m)},\tag{1}$$
where ${k \brack n}$ are the [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind), can be represented as a linear combination of Riemann $\zeta$-functions with rational coefficients.

Namely, the following identity holds for $0\le m<n$ :
$$
S(n,m)=\frac{1}{m!}\sum_{i=0}^{m}{m \brack i}\zeta(n+1-i).\tag{2}
$$
Observe that the sum of coefficients at $\zeta$-functions is equal to 1.

Surprisingly, *Mathematica* knows the analytical result of summation (1) only for $m=0$.

Can the identity (2) be derived directly from (1) by "elementary" means? If necessary, the result for $m=0$ can be regarded as given. An "elementary" proof of it can be found [elsewhere](https://eudml.org/doc/117400). My attempts to apply it onto the case of non-zero $m$ have failed.