# Evaluation of : $ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^2 (x+1)}{x}$?

Tags: integration, polylogarithm

I have accrossed in my text book this integral :$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^2 (x+1)}{x}$  and i used integration by part but i can't get any result compatible with [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+(+log%C2%B2(x%2B1)%2Fx)),+x%3D0+to+1) , i'm really confused how this integral had a relationship with polylogarithm function and why it's closed form result depend to the Riemann zeta function  , function which i didn't know before, then my question is : how do i evaluate this integral : $$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^2 (x+1)}{x}$$  ?

Comment: I think you have idea about polylogarithms $Li$ i.e. Jonquiere function.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2733815/293846) you can find expression for more general case.